# Quiero realizar un código de una tarea en java NetBeans

Tags: java

Donde me permita vender un boleto de un autobús para un viaje x (No importa el destino), el boleto cuesta 20 dlls, solo que debo considerar que el autobús debe llevar 46 personas(no mas no menos).

y considerar que 4 espacios ya se vendieron, y los espacios se divide en A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2... así sucesivamente hasta que estén los 46 espacios, pero el sistema no puede vender los ya ocupados, y deberá decir cuales están disponibles, y si están llenos deberá mandar un print en consola de que ya están ocupados todo.

lo eh intentado con arreglos pero no me sale, y ya estoy cerrado mentalmente!

ayuda! pls!

es en consola de netbeans

Comment: Te voy a dar una idea porque lo veo jodio de hacer. Yo me olvidaria de array que es jodio usa o List o quizas mejor una matriz list cada linea es A B C D y cada columna 12 3 4.
Eso po un lado por otro tienen que ser 48 espacio o los calculos no dan si cada letra tiene 4 numeros
Luego necesitas pedir por consola fila en forma de letra y asiento eso lo pasas a un bucle for doble para que recorra fila y columna y busque dicho asiento si es null entonces lo agrega y te dice vendido si es diferente de null entonces te dice que esta ocupado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta seria tu clase Bus. El main ya no te lo hago que no tiene misterio creas un objeto bus y vas llamando a los metodos

```
public class Bus {

    private String[][] asiento;
    private int precio;
    private int columna;
    private int fila;

    public Bus(String[][] asiento, int precio, int columna, int fila) {
        this.asiento = asiento;
        this.precio = 20;
        this.setColumna(columna);
        this.setFila(fila);
    }

    public Bus() {
        asiento = new String[columna][fila];
    }

    public String[][] getAsiento() {
        return asiento;
    }

    public void setAsiento(String[][] asiento) {
        this.asiento = asiento;
    }

    public int getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(int precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public int getColumna() {
        return columna;
    }

    public void setColumna(int columna) {
        if (columna < 4) {
            this.columna = columna;
        }
    }

    public int getFila() {
        return fila;
    }

    public void setFila(int fila) {
        if (fila < 12) {
            this.fila = fila;
        }
    }

    public String venderBillete(int columna, int fila) {
        String resultado = "";
        if (asiento[columna][fila] != null) {
            asiento[columna][fila] = "vendido";
            resultado += "billete vendido";
        } else {
            resultado += "el asiento esta ocupado";
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    public int costoBillete(int numBilletes){
        int total = this.precio * numBilletes;
        return total;
    }
}
```